# Unable to rendered the pagblock after clicking the button

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

Initially when pageload and first time rendered working ,but when i am clicking again save button the pageblock should hide if there is no record in pageblocktable. Please see below code

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="searchpagecontroller" >
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchtext}" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search" reRender="out" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
           <apex:pageBlock title="Search Account Here" rendered="{!abool}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
        <apex:column >
        <apex:outputText>{!a.id}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column >
        <apex:outputText>{!a.Name}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                  </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

---

Controller

```
public class SearchPageController {
public string searchtext{get;set;}
public list<account> acc{get;set;}
public Boolean abool {get;set;}
public SearchPageController(apexpages.StandardController stdcon){
}
public void search(){
    abool=true;
    string searchtext='select name,id from account where name like \'%'+searchtext+'%\' Limit 20';  
    acc=database.query(searchtext);
}
public void clear(){
    acc.clear();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling a scenario when no records are found. You need to make `abool` false if no records are found. Just add below line in your Apex controller method `search`

```
if(acc.size() > 0)
    abool=true;
else
    abool = false;
```

Make `abool` `true` only if `acc` size is greater than zero else make it as `false`. This will prevent showing `pageblock` if there are no records.

So ideally speaking this is how your `search` method should be:

```
public void search(){
    string searchtext='select name,id from account where name like \'%'+searchtext+'%\' Limit 20';  
    acc=database.query(searchtext);

    if(acc.size() > 0)
        abool=true;
    else
        abool = false;
}
```